# Spring security makes a session when a user access the log in page

Tags: spring, authentication, session, spring-security

I'm making log in page, following official guide.

I want to add a function which makes redirect to home if a user join.

The logic is like this.

1. A user join with email, password and username.
2. Joinpage redirect to log in page.
3. if there is authentication, directly go to home.

How can I redirect to home with authentication?

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm(@ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm) {

        return "login/loginForm";
    }
}


public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests() // 인가 요청 받기
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/join",
                        "/css/**", "/*.ico", "/error").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

basically, the security generates user session along the SessionCreationPolicy value when the user logins successfully.
if you want to change the session system to stateless system.
but following the below code.

```java
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    }
```

and then, you need to set the authentication object.

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("principal", "credentials", null));
```